# Mediation Analysis for Mixed Models

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model, mediation

I would like to conduct a mediation analysis in combination with mixed models. To create the mixed model, I used the lmer-package in R.

My models look like the following:

- `fit.totaleffect <- lmer(Y ~ X1 +(1| ID)  + Xc2 + Xc3, data = df)`
- `fit.mediator    <- lmer(M ~ X1 +(1| ID)  + Xc2 + Xc3, data = df)`
- `fit.dv          <- lmer(Y ~ M + X1 +(1| ID)  + Xc2 + Xc3, data = df)`

Now, I use the following function to perform the mediation analysis:

- `results <- mediation::mediate(fit.mediator, fit.dv, treat='X1', mediator='M')`

The results of `summary(results)` are

```
                Estimate 95% CI Lower 95% CI Upper p-value    
ACME            -807.244    -1055.228      -589.24  <2e-16 ***
ADE             -484.139     -864.027      -146.44    0.01 ** 
Total Effect   -1291.384    -1694.853      -905.94  <2e-16 ***
Prop. Mediated     0.623        0.448         0.87  <2e-16 ***
```

**My question:** How do I get the value for the significance of the indirect effect? Do I use this the `Prop. Mediatied` row? I have already googled and found only examples using bootstrapping. However, bootstrapping doesn't work for lmer.

Comment: I would suggest you read Imai et al's various papers on this topic, as you are using their software. See https://imai.fas.harvard.edu/research/files/mediationR2.pdf and https://imai.fas.harvard.edu/research/files/mediationR.pdf and https://imai.fas.harvard.edu/research/files/mediationP.pdf

Comment: I read the papers. However, I am new to this topic and do not really understand what to do :(

Comment: I would suggest reading more broadly on the topic of mediation and/or pairing up with someone who is well-versed in the methodology. The work of Kristopher Preacher (http://quantpsy.org/medn.htm) would be a good place to start. He's done a ton of work on multilevel mediation.

Comment: Okay, thank you. So, I guess there is no "easy and short" answer?

Comment: The easy answer is that ACME is the parameter you are interested in. However, it is important that you have a good understanding of mediation more generally, then mediation in multilevel contexts, and what your chosen software is doing.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the information :)

Comment: Just to confirm, the `fit.totaleffect` formula is redundant for the `mediate` function, correct? Because you only use `fit-mediator` and `fit.dv`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ACME` is an acronym for "Average Causal Mediation Effects"

`ADE` is an acronym for "Average Direct Effects"

`Total Effect` is the sum of `ACME` and `ADE`

So the "Indirect Effect" that you are seeking is simply the row for`ACME`